# Make URL's case sensitive

Tags: php, apache, url

Can somebody help me in resolving this.

I have a website on Linux server with Apache.
Our customer wants that the URL's used in the site should be case Sensitive

ie. if the link is http://www.example.com/Product-Roadmap if written as http://www.example.com/product-roadmap, it should give 404 page not found

As fas as I know, links in linux server are case sensitive, but in our server they are not. 
What should I do to make them case sensitive.

Comment: You probably run some kind of web application on the server, maybe a php Content Management System?

Comment: http://www.wisegeek.com/are-urls-case-sensitive.htm

Comment: Are you using a PHP Framework like Zend or Symfony?

Comment: Then the URLs are not interpreted by Apache but by the Joomla router. This information is important, you should add it to your question.

Comment: i m new to it... can u tell me what changes I shoulld make

Answer (score 0):

URL can't themselves be case-(in)sensitive, it is their interpreter who is. It means that you need to change the way they are interpreted in your server side application, and since we don't know what is it, I can't give any more details.